# Why doesn't my Windows 7 laptop have a sleep option?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, sleep, control-panel

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad W520 running Windows 7. It is supposed to be identical to the previous machine that it replaced.

I want to customize the laptop's behavior when the lid is closed, when I push the power or sleep button, etc.

However, when I go to the Power Options control panel, I don't get any choices to put the computer to sleep, as shown in the screenshot below. Normally, Sleep is the default option for many (all?) of these actions, but the option is completely missing.

[image: Power Options control panel screenshot--Sleep option is not present]

Any suggestions how I can get the Sleep option? The option was there on the previous (supposedly identical) laptop, and it is also present on a different Windows 7 laptop that I use.

Comment: Are those boxes actually empty, or did you blot them out for some reason? If they're actually Empty, then that's pretty weird.

Comment: They are empty; that is exactly how they look on my screen. I suspect it is because they should say Sleep but for some reason the option is not present.

Comment: Is this computer on a work (domain) network?

Comment: Something to try... Open a command-line (as administrator) and run `powercfg –restoredefaultschemes`.  This should reset all the power schemes to default, and hopefully restore the Sleep choice.  Also ensure you're using the latest video and chipset drivers as offered at Lenovo's site for your model,